# how to decrease the application size

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My problem is that my application size is very high,

is there any idea to reduce size of application?

if i make application without content and content is uploaded my server then how i sync the application with content put on my server?

i want to know that once user download application after that when he use application then we stream the content and save his document folder.
once user stream then never required for streaming.

is it possible????

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible that you can download your content and can save to application's document folder, when user runs your application for the first time. Thought it may affect the first impression to your user as it will take time to download.

Answer (score 2):

Reducing the size of your application depends on the TYPE of contents of your application.  I highly doubt that the application code is the cause, and since you did not mention what they are I am assuming they are some kind of resource.

If your resources are images, try to use image compression programs.  Or convert them to smaller sized images or optimize the images.

If your resources are documents / text files / files that have a high compression ratio when zipped.  Then you can try to zip your resources and access them inside the compressed file (this will mean additional coding, and probably slower in performance).

These are just examples.

It is not advisable to stream large contents because it uses the network bandwidth which, depending on the user's plan, can cause a big spike in phone bills.

Comment: i am using songs in my application